# Javascript switch dosen't work correctly

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, innerhtml

I am trying to make a one-pager that in its left there will be a fixed div and in this div will be an image.

The image will be changed by the id of the div that the mouse will be above.

I wrote this function:

```
var number ='number';
document.onmouseover = function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.target.id);

    switch (obj.target.id) {

        case 1:
            var number = "a";
            break;
        case 2:
            var number = "b";
            break;
        case 3:
            var number = "c";
            break;
        case 4:
            var number = "d";
            break;
        case 5:
            var number = "e";
            break;
        case 6:
            var number = "f";
            break;
    }

    document.getElementById("numberdiv").innerHTML = "this div id is " + number;
}
```

I have one main problem, the switch doesn't receive the data from the  `obj.target.id`.

this is my HTML

```
<div class="div" id="1">1</div>
<div class="div" id="2">2</div>
<div class="div" id="3">3</div>
<div class="div" id="4">4</div>
<div class="div" id="5">5</div>
<div class="div" id="6">6</div>
<div id="numberdiv"></div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/davseveloff/u1guaer1/)

Comment: This should have been easy enough to debug. The log would have shown that `obj.target.id` was a string, whereas the cases in the switch statement are trying to compare it to a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you need to parse `parseInt(obj.target.id,10)` or convert `case 1` to `case "1"`, Since `obj.target.id` is  string it will not match to any case so either you need to convert switch value to number or case value to string.

```js
var number = 'number';
document.onmouseover = function(obj) {
  console.log(obj.target.id);

  switch (parseInt(obj.target.id, 10)) {

    case 1:
      var number = "a";
      break;
    case 2:
      var number = "b";
      break;
    case 3:
      var number = "c";
      break;
    case 4:
      var number = "d";
      break;
    case 5:
      var number = "e";
      break;
    case 6:
      var number = "f";
      break;
  }

  document.getElementById("numberdiv").innerHTML = "this div id is " + number;
}
```

```css
.div {
  height: 200px;
}
body:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
body:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}
#numberdiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  float: right;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div" id="1">1</div>
  <div class="div" id="2">2</div>
  <div class="div" id="3">3</div>
  <div class="div" id="4">4</div>
  <div class="div" id="5">5</div>
  <div class="div" id="6">6</div>
  <div id="numberdiv"></div>
</body>
```

---

OR

```js
var number = 'number';
document.onmouseover = function(obj) {
  console.log(obj.target.id);

  switch (obj.target.id) {

    case "1":
      var number = "a";
      break;
    case "2":
      var number = "b";
      break;
    case "3":
      var number = "c";
      break;
    case "4":
      var number = "d";
      break;
    case "5":
      var number = "e";
      break;
    case "6":
      var number = "f";
      break;
  }

  document.getElementById("numberdiv").innerHTML = "this div id is " + number;
}
```

```css
.div {
  height: 200px;
}
body:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
body:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}
#numberdiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  float: right;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div" id="1">1</div>
  <div class="div" id="2">2</div>
  <div class="div" id="3">3</div>
  <div class="div" id="4">4</div>
  <div class="div" id="5">5</div>
  <div class="div" id="6">6</div>
  <div id="numberdiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: great! it worked, of course, i converted the case numbers to "x" . works great, tnx

Answer (score 2):

Anything that is read from DOM is **String**. `switch` cases doesn't coerce the type to match specific case. Use `parseInt(obj.target.id, 10)`.

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/u1guaer1/2/)

A better approach will be to use an Object instead of `switch`.

```
var number;

var numbers = {
    1: 'a',
    2: 'b',
    3: 'c',
    4: 'd',
    5: 'e',
    6: 'f'
};
document.onmouseover = function (obj) {
    var number = numbers[obj.target.id];
    document.getElementById("numberdiv").innerHTML = "this div id is " + number;
}
```

```js
var number;

var numbers = {
  1: 'a',
  2: 'b',
  3: 'c',
  4: 'd',
  5: 'e',
  6: 'f'
};

document.onmouseover = function(obj) {
  var number = numbers[obj.target.id];
  document.getElementById("numberdiv").innerHTML = "this div id is " + number;
}
```

```css
.div {
  height: 200px;
}
body:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
body:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}
#numberdiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  float: right;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div" id="1">1</div>
  <div class="div" id="2">2</div>
  <div class="div" id="3">3</div>
  <div class="div" id="4">4</div>
  <div class="div" id="5">5</div>
  <div class="div" id="6">6</div>
  <div id="numberdiv"></div>
</body>
```

Or Array, if the numbers are sequential

```
var number;
var numbers = [undefined, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

document.onmouseover = function (obj) {
    var number = numbers[obj.target.id];
    document.getElementById("numberdiv").innerHTML = "this div id is " + number;
}
```

```js
var number;
var numbers = [undefined, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

document.onmouseover = function(obj) {
  var number = numbers[obj.target.id];
  document.getElementById("numberdiv").innerHTML = "this div id is " + number;
}
```

```css
.div {
  height: 200px;
}
body:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
body:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}
#numberdiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  float: right;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div" id="1">1</div>
  <div class="div" id="2">2</div>
  <div class="div" id="3">3</div>
  <div class="div" id="4">4</div>
  <div class="div" id="5">5</div>
  <div class="div" id="6">6</div>
  <div id="numberdiv"></div>
</body>
```